# What it used for <sf:errors path="" cssClass="error"> in jsp?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, jstl

I saw an exemple on internet with:

```
 <sf:errors path="firstName" cssClass="error"></sf:errors>
```

The errors comes from bindingResult in controller?I don't understand...Can you give me un exemple?

Comment: Take a look at this http://codetutr.com/2013/05/28/spring-mvc-form-validation/

Answer (score 4):

To bind result used spring framework validator Errors Interface i.e.[Errors API Doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/1.2.x/api/org/springframework/validation/Errors.html).

**Example:**
Add error by adding your values in `rejectValue()` method with give key exactly equal to the path which specified in `form errors` tag,

i.e.

```
@Override
public void validate(Object target, Errors errors) {
    errors.rejectValue("password", "Enter password");
}
```

then use form errors tag for showing error,

```
<form:errors path="password"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

The field error messages are generated by validators associated with the controller. You can use the  tag to render those field error messages.

See this nice tutorial http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-form-errors-tag-example/ for more information.